# How to put Next link before last page number in cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

In my pagination,there is duplicate last page number.

[This is my current pagination.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMkc.jpg)

```
<?php
      $last = $this->Paginator->counter('{:pages}');
      $first = $last - $last + 1;           
?>
<ol>
   <?php
echo $this->Paginator->first($first,array('tag'=>'li','currentTag'=>'a',
'escape' => false));

echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo;', array('tag' => 'li',  'title' => __('Previous page'), 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'disabled'));

 echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => '4', 'separator' => false, 'tag' => 'li', 'currentTag' => 'a'));

echo $this->Paginator->next('&raquo;', array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'title' => __('Next page'), 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'disabled'));

echo $this->Paginator->last($last, array('tag' => 'li', 'currentTag' => 'a', 'escape' => false));

?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this method $this->Paginator->current($model), This will give you current page number

```
if($this->Paginator->current($model) != $last) {
  echo $this->Paginator->last($last, array('rest of options'));
}
```

I hope this helps you. here is the link where you can get for information on paginator helper class.

[Paginator Helper Class CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper::last)